# What options can be specified in `.wsh` files?

Tags: vbscript, jscript, wsh

I am following [this nice tutorial](http://wsh2.uw.hu/ch01d.html), part of the *"Microsoft Windows Script Host 2.0 Developer's Guide"* online book by [Günter Born](https://twitter.com/etguenni). There he mentioned the interesting `.wsh` files where one can specify a couple of not-very-interesting runtime properties for the JScript/VBScript s. For example:

- `example1.vbs`:

```
WScript.Echo "Hello world!"
```

accompanies with `example1.wsh`:

```
[ScriptFile]
Path=.\example.vbs
[Options]
Timeout=10
DisplayLogo=1
```

if ran in the cmd with `cscript example1.wsh` will print out the so called logo:

> Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812 
>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

and if ran with `wscript example1.vbs`, the window:

will close after 10 seconds.

- while for the `example2.js` file:

```
WScript.Echo('Hello world!');
```

accompanied with `example2.wsh`:

```
[ScriptFile]
Path=.\example.vbs
[Options]
Timeout=20
DisplayLogo=0
```

no "logo" will be shown in the console and the GUI version will close at 20 seconds.

now I'm curious to know what other options can we specify in those `.wsh` files. Is there an official reference for their syntax provided by Microsoft at all? References and examples would be highly appreciated.

**P.S.1.** I found [this reference documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/h8fe3wt9(v=vs.84)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). There another boolean option `BatchMode=0` or `BatchMode=1` is mentioned where the latter:

> Specifies batch mode, which does not display alerts, scripting errors, or input prompts.

Now I wonder if one can mention all [other options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wscript) that `cscript.exe`/`wscript.exe` accept as well.

**P.S.2.** I also learned that the `.wsh`s are called "Windows Script Host control file"s.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click a vbs file and choose Properties then Script tab you will see two options - `Timeout` and `DisplayLogo`.

The Windows Script Technologies help file is here http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe

- JScript
- VBScript
- Script Runtime

  └ Dictionary object

  └ FileSystemObject (FSO)

  └ Script Encoder
- Windows Script Components
- Windows Script Host
- Windows Script Interfaces

Also be aware that no one uses `.wsh` files. It was an idea programmers didn't take too.

Other libraries

- Databases and binary streams - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/introduction-to-ado-programming
- WBEM (WMI) for managing systems - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/about-wmi
- XML and getting internet files - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms759148(v=vs.85)
- Windows Explorer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/objects

Comment: What do the "Other libraries" have to do with the question or the answer for that matter?